# How to add custom class to system classLoader?

Tags: android, bundle, classloader, parcelable, badparcelableexception

I have two custom classes:

`class A: Parcelable{}
class B: Parcelable{}`

When I save and restore them (during rotation) at each place I need set classLoader to Bundle. Otherwise I will get `BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling`

Also I need compare content of two bundles and here it looks dirty to set custom classLoader aech time... So I am pretty sure that there is some way to add custom classes to system classLoader (or something similar action) so this problem can be solved on application level, but not locally.

Will be glad any help!

Comment: Why not simply create a method that encapsulates the logic that you do not want to repeat?

Comment: As I know there is no way to set 2 or more classLoader to Bundle at the same time... Even if it is, but it'not, it doesn't make sense if there is way to do it once per all app.